# Design Matrix for Client Input

Tags: design, client

I have a question regarding client input in the UX process. I'm planing a Stakeholder Interview to kick off this project as it's a complete redesign of a existing web system. But I'd like to see where stakeholders are leaning in design questions and I'd like them to rate a "Design Matrix".

Something like this:

- Traditional vs Modern,
- Bold & Vivid vs Dull & Grey,
- Complex vs Simple steps,
- Warm vs Cool,
- Accessibility vs beautiful design

On a scale on 1-6.

But my question is, where can I find more information about this "Matrix" cause I know I've seen it somewhere?

Comment: I have created something similar before, but you need to be very careful about the wording because you don't want to bias people to choose one over the other. For example, complex vs simple steps will invariably lead people to select simple steps.

Comment: I agree with @michael Lai... I'm afraid you're going to bias the stakeholders with the words you're using. If you're looking for matrix feedback like this then provide relevant UX examples to choose from and take the labels off. You'll quickly know what they like/dislike. And in the end make sure you're providing a ux experience that fits the end users instead of trying to fit it into a matrix of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Traditional vs Modern,
>   Bold & Vivid vs Dull & Grey,
>   Warm vs Cool,

These are visual aesthetic attributes. While certainly a part of UX, I'd say this is really more the domain of branding and design.

Also note that 'dull and grey' is a leading phrase. Something can be dull and vivid and bold and gray as well.

> Complex vs Simple steps,

Not sure the benefit of asking this. Does anyone vote for complex? :)

> Accessibility vs beautiful design

These are not mutually exclusive concepts. In fact, they shouldn't be. ONe should strive for beautiful, accessible design.

Now, that doesn't answer your specific question, of course, but maybe helps.

As for what this matrix is, I'd say it could fall into a number of areas:

- The [Creative Brief](http://www.mohawkconnects.com/feltandwire/2011/02/08/the-creative-brief-10-things-it-must-include/)
- A [Brand Positioning Document](http://beloved-brands.com/2012/05/06/brand-positioning-statement/)
- A form of a [mood board](http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design/mood-boards-812470)

Answer (score 1):

I remember a Microsoft study where they used a number of adjectives and let users/stakeholders pick a selected number (e.g. top 5) that they believe best describes the application that is currently being used, and what they want it to be. If anyone remembers or can find this reference that would be great.

However, to provide a design matrix like this requires a reasonably good understanding of the users and the system, because you need to work out the scope of the project and the relevant attributes to avoid bias in user decisions.

Also, it is important to break it down into broad level categories to help analyse where the primary need for improvement comes from. For example, I would probably use something like this:

1. Visual attributes
2. Functional attributes
3. Technical attributes

Then within each of these sections there are complementary and opposing attributes. So for visual attributes you might see things like:

- Flat versus skeuomorphic design style (with some visual examples)
- Rich colours versus monotone/accessible colour palette
- Extensive use of icons/images versus text based display

For functional attributes you might see:

- Single step processes versus wizard/multi-step processes
- Deep nested hierarchy versus flat/broad navigation
- Discovery based interaction versus guided workflows

I'll update this as I find the references, but you should get an idea of the way you need to word the attributes to avoid bias.